# How could we define the existence of an object/element in the Euclidean space?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, philosophy

Let X be an object/element, What does it mean when I say "X is an object in the Euclidean space"? in other words, What differs an existed object from an unexisted one in the Euclidean space?

Comment: Which type of Euclidean space?

Comment: The two-dimensional space, but generally, any definitions for higher spaces are welcome also..

Answer (score 1):

Elements (points) of Euclidean geometry are taken as primitive notions, with no further explanation. Their existence is postulated. Every other thing existing "in" the space would be described as collections of these points.

Comment: @AhmedElsobky It is only shady if you misunderstand the way it is used. You keep asking for it to be defined (less shady) but there is no sense in defining it any further. You have to stop somewhere, or else you have an infinitely deep chain of definitions. "Point" is just a logical starting place to take for granted.

Comment: @AhmedElsobky I would encourage you to research some of the mainstream sets of axioms for Euclidean geometry, such as Hilbert's axioms and Tarski's axioms, before spending a lot of time on homemade speculation. Also, from your comment it's pretty clear you do not really know what godel's theorem is about: maybe you should hold off on invoking it too often.